# ctx.bot.get_user unable in ctx to use while in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem in my code which says name 'ctx' is not defined
this is step to make id that i have got by somebody saying '.give @name'. this menioned part will be read as id. SO, I want to change id to username which is 'something#1324'

```
import discord
from discord import Client
import json
import os
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
client =commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\junes\PycharmProjects\discordbot')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.give'):
        msg = message.content.split()
        a= str(msg[1])
        await message.channel.send('test link code:' + a)
        print(a)
        user = ctx.bot.get_user(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't have **context** in `on_message` event. There's only **message** object, so you should use **client** for `get_user()`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.give'):
        msg = message.content.split()
        a= str(msg[1])
        await message.channel.send('test link code:' + a)
        print(a)
        user = client.get_user(a)
```

Comment: If I do this, I get 'none' if I print user

Comment: What a version of Discord.py?